# What is a good way to register two different mousedown events one after the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to send JSON to the server. The format is of the form `{ "src": X, "dest": Y }`.

`src` includes an array of properties from the first item I clicked. `destination` is the second item I click on the screen.

Right now this is the basic structure that I have:

```
$('img').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    // parse json for src and validate input
    let obj = {};
    obj.src = myvalidatedinput"
    // ...
});
```

How do I make sure that I click once to fill the `src` property of the object, then on the second click I get the `dest` property of the object? Also, at that point I want to stop keeping track of clicks, and I start over.

Answer (score 2):

Define the object outside of the handler. You can then set the required property based on what values have already been set. Something like this:

```
let obj = {};
$('img').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (!obj.src) {
        obj.src = /* get the src property value */;
    } else if (!obj.dest) {
        obj.dest = /* get the dest property value */;
        // send AJAX here

        // reset to start again on next mousedown:
        obj = {};
    }
});
```